Display first letter of each word in Libreoffice Calc cell
Column A contains cells formatted as FirstName LastName. Column B is intended to convert one of those cells into initials. How can I take a cell with the value Example Name and display it as EN?
I've seen solutions using macros, but I would like to avoid using them if possible.

This can be done with a simple formula in the form of =left(A1)&mid(A1,find(" ", A1)+1,1)
The left(cell) function looks for the leftmost character. The mid(cell,start,length) function returns length number characters from start and the find(character, cell) function gives the index of the first character found in cell, in this case the space " " between firstname and lastname. Since we need the character after that, we add one.

Oh that's clever. I didn't think to use the character position of the FIND+1 from the space
